# Issue with `display: table` followed by scrollable content in flexbox on IE Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container which is flexbox (`display: flex`). It has two children children, I have div with `display: table` and one scrollable element. On firefox and chrome, it works fine ([codepen](https://codepen.io/vishtree/pen/BwKGJB?editors=1100) for same).

But on Microsoft Edge, as show in following snapshot, scrollable content somehow gets overlapped with table element.

Screenshot for Microsoft Edge (which is the issue):
[image: On IE Edge]

Screenshot for chrome (which works perfectly fine and which is expected behaviour):

[image]

Any help/reasoning/solution regarding this would be appreciated.

Following is the HTML part:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Hi, this is the table</p>
        <p>Subtext for table</p>
    </div>
    <div class="below-table">
        <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
        <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
        ...
        <!--   Lot of such text, so as to make it scrollable   -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    background-color: blue;
}
.below-table {
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Wait, with "IE Edge" you mean "Edge", right? Not "both IE and Edge"?

Comment: Ahh I just mean Edge. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Pete But I have given codepen link for the same in question itself (which contains code). Also I have mentioned the desired behaviour. I went for codepen instead of posting code here itself since it's quite easy for anyone to debug there itself.

Comment: @pete I have corrected the question as you asked.

Comment: @pete Another reason why I prefer codepen instead of posting code here is, lot of people just give or guess the random suggestions without even thinking. Going to codepen intimidates them to try it once. Thats all. But I understand the reasoning about links going obsolete :)

Comment: @Vishtree, you can create stack snippets here, It also then allows users to copy the code into their answer.  If you wish to add a codepen link that is fine but if you don't include your code in the question, [your question is off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and will be closed

Comment: Ok gotcha .. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge seems to disregard the content of tables if they are direct descendants of flex, if you add a wrapper div around the table, it should solve your issue for Edge

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  background-color: blue;
}

.below-table {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <p>Hi, this is the table</p>
      <p>Subtext for table</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="below-table">
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    <p>And this is bwlow the table</p>
    ...
    <!--   Lot of such text, so as to make it scrollable   -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry for one small confusion @pete. I was not supposed to fix height on `.below-table` class. So if I remove `height: 200px` from `.below-table` then it creates issue on Edge. I fixed that in the code which I posted in question, but forgot to update the codepen link before.

Comment: It happens with the codepen which you have given as well (if I remove height property from `.below-table`). Here is the snapshot on Edge: https://ibb.co/hUFCUQ

Comment: Ah yeah, I see the problem now.  Funnily enough codepen has just gone down!  Is there any reason to have the blue cell as a table?

Comment: Yeah actually, thats the use-case in my project. Without table, it works perfectly fine otherwise. I want to make it work with `display: table` :)

Comment: I think you need a wrapper div then - see update to above snippet - I can't edit my pen

Comment: Ohh yeah ... that seems to work. Seems a little hacky for production code. 
 But Microsoft browsers always demand hacks anyways. Thanks alot @pete.

Comment: If you can edit the first few lines of answer as per our latest discussion, it will avoid confusion for future users as well and I'll be more than happy to mark it as accepted with it :)

Comment: Edited as per comments

Comment: Thanks once again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154934/discussion-between-vishtree-and-pete).